# Guardar múltiples valores de declaración For en Firebase

Tags: java, android, array, firebase, lista

¡Hola, comunidad! Es una duda básica pero de la cual aún no encuentro la respuesta.

Tengo un GridView con varios botones de estilo CardView. Al momento de dar clic en cualquiera de ellos, se imprime un valor asignado por una declaración For.

```
for (int i = 0; i <servicesGrid.getChildCount(); i++) {
    final int serviceId = i;
    final CardView cardView = (CardView) servicesGrid.getChildAt(i);
    cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (cardView.getCardBackgroundColor().getDefaultColor() == -1) {
                cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00796b"));



                List<Integer> servicesList = Arrays.asList(serviceId);
                Map userInfo = new HashMap();
                userInfo.put("Servicios", serviceId);
                mCreadoresDatabase.child("Servicios").push().setValue(servicesList).toString();

            } else {
                cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

                List<Integer> servicesList = Arrays.asList(serviceId);
                Map userInfo = new HashMap();
                mCreadoresDatabase.child("Servicios").removeValue();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}`

Este valor es guardado después en Firebase.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, al poder clickear varios botones, quiero que se guarden todos los valores seleccionados y en este momento solamente se sustituye el valor existente por el nuevo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les agradecería me pudieran orientar en este sentido. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta aqui:

```
List<Integer> servicesList = Arrays.asList(serviceId);
mCreadoresDatabase.child("Servicios").push().setValue(servicesList).toString();
```

Siempre que haces click seteas una lista nueva con un unico valor.

Lo que debes hacer entonces es:

- Sacar la lista fuera del contexto del click para poder almacenar todos los botones seleccionados.
- Agregar/Eliminar de la lista el valor cuando se hace click
- Setear la lista entera en firebase.

Quedaria algo asi:

```
ArrayList<Integer> servicesList = new ArrayList();

private void agregarServicio(Integer serviceId) {
    servicesList.add(serviceId);
    updateDatabase();
}
private void eliminarServicio(Integer serviceId){
    servicesList.remove(serviceId);
    updateDatabase();
}
private void updateDatabase(){
    mCreadoresDatabase.child("Servicios").setValue(servicesList).toString();
}
```

Y asi lo integras con lo que ya tienes

```
for (int i = 0; i <servicesGrid.getChildCount(); i++) {
    final int serviceId = i;
    final CardView cardView = (CardView) servicesGrid.getChildAt(i);
    cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (cardView.getCardBackgroundColor().getDefaultColor() == -1) {
                cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00796b"));    
                agregarServicio(serviceId)
            } else {
                cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                eliminarServicio(serviceId)
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: ¡Estimado, Erick! Te agradezco mucho la aclaración. Efectivamente me sirvió. Únicamente quite el ".push" del método "updateDatabase" para que no creara un registro diferente. ¡¡Muchas gracias!! Llevaba varios días intentado corregirlo.

Comment: Genial! ya edite la respuesta para que no quede con el error.